# Unity3d - Panel not work properly in android platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi guys I have a problem with a Panel function.

I am trying to show panel when health reach 0.

When I tried run the game in Unity, the panel show up when my health reach 0, but when I run it on Android platform, the panel doesn't show up when my health reach 0.

So far, here is my code :

```
public class popupover : MonoBehaviour {

     public GameObject panel;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         panel.SetActive (false);
     }

     void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
     {
             if (GameControlScript.health == 0)

             {
                 panel.SetActive (true);
         }
     }
 }
```

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Does this code run perfectly on Unity?

Comment: Can you post your GameControlScript script and how you're changing the health]?

Comment: yes sir, it's working perfectly on Unity

Comment: GameControlScript you can check here : https://pastebin.com/2hgJZSVt

Comment: I think the problem is with "how" you place your panel in UI. scale and resolution issue.